# Build fails when using closure

Tags: swift, xcode6

I am trying to use closures in Swift, but for some reason the build always fails without an meaningfull error message. 
I always get

> Command
>   /Applications/Xcode6-Beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   failed with exit code 254

It happens when I add a function which has another function as a parameter, like this:

```
func averageOfFunction(a:Float,b:Float,f:(Float -> Float)) -> Float {
    return (f(a) + f(b)) / 2
}
```

Without this function the code compiles with no errors. Does anybody know what I can do?

Comment: You should file a radar about this (radar.apple.com). This should be a compiler error - instead it crashes the compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your function that you want to have as a parameter is written wrong. So instead of

```
func averageOfFunction(a:Float,b:Float,f:(Float -> Float)) -> Float {
    return (f(a) + f(b)) / 2
}
```

write

```
func averageOfFunction(a:Float,b:Float,f:(Float) -> Float ) -> Float {
    return (f(a) + f(b)) / 2
}
```

That should work.

Comment: You are right, it works now. I thought the function was correct because I took it from an tutorial and it also failed with another function from another tutorial. Seems like both tutorials are wrong.

Comment: I tried your code in my playground and it worked.. But from apples documentation, this is the way to write this.. :)

Comment: Do we need the parentheses around the first (Float) of the f argument? Not used in Apple's examples and `f: Float -> Float` works the same

Comment: If you have only one parameter, you don't need it. But two or more, you have to write them down.